# C++ C4834 error moving from VS2017 to VS2019

Tags: c++

I am getting this warning, until now I didn't get any warning :

> error C2220: the following warning is treated as an error 
> warning C4834: discarding return value of function with 'nodiscard' attribute

```
template <typename T>
static void quick_hull(std::vector<T> &points)
{
    points = hull(points);
    // Remove successive duplicates
    std::unique(begin(points), end(points), [](const T &a, const T &b) { return (a.x == b.x) && (a.y == b.y); });
}
```

Can you please explain why does this happen ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`std::unique` does not remove elements. It only reorders them in such a way that all unique values are moved to the front. Then it returns an iterator pointing to the element after the last unique value.

You need this iterator to actually remove the duplicate elements with a container specific method. Without it you don't know where the duplicates start and MSVC warns you, that you are discarding this important return value.

Your code should be

```
auto new_end = std::unique(begin(points), end(points), ...); // move duplicates to end
points.erase(new_end, end(points)); // actually removes duplicates from vector
```

Comment: Which is why the MSVC stl decided to mark `std::unique` as nodiscard... Which is the root of the issue here.

Comment: ok I think i get it. so until now unique gave me for example the 4 unique points out of 10 i had. however it kept the other 6 which are redundant.. your code removes those.

Comment: @Gilad Correct. That's because it operates only on iterators and doesn't know anything about the container they belong to.

Comment: Note that `std::unique` doesn't "move duplicates to the back". It's not a partition algorithm. The only data that moves are non-duplicates to the left and they overwrite what was there previously. The elements after the new logical end have unspecified values.